# Python: typeerror: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

i am a beginner learning python. I am trying to make a program that shuffles a deck of cards without the use of random.shuffle or random.choice. When I use my program, I can shuffle my list and it prints out, and then I can print out the original deck of cards. However, when i go to shuffle the deck again the error occurs.

[image: The error that occurs]

Can anyone help?

```
from random import randint
#deckbuild function creates the deck of 52 cards from a normal deck
def deckbuild():
  #program will create a deck of cards when the program is launched
  cards = []
  signs = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
  cardletters = ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
  deck = []
  #Adding content to the deck
  for i in range(2,11):
    cards.append(str(i))
    #this will generate the numbers 2 to 10 hat will be used for the cards
  for r in range(4):
    cards.append(cardletters[r])
    #adding card letters to cards
  for final in range(4):
    for k in range(13):
      fincard = (cards[k] + " of " + signs[final])
      deck.append(fincard)
      #adds the final product of cards into a list that will be used to put into functions
  for numofcard in range(52):
    return deck

#List of functions that will be used
#shuffle function takes in a list and randomly shuffles it
def shuffle(listinput):
  list_range = range(0, len(listinput))
  for i in list_range:
    j = randint(list_range[0], list_range[-1])
    listinput[i], listinput[j] = listinput[j], listinput[i]
  return listinput

def printdeck(x):
  print('Here is your deck of cards ')
  #prints the deck in a vertical list
  for num in range(52):
    print(x[num])


print('Hello, welcome to the card shuffler program')
print('''This program allows you to shuffle a full deck of cards in a digital world''')
loop = True
while(loop == True):
  loop = False
  carddeck = deckbuild()
  print('Here is a list of things you can do')
  print('1. Shuffle and view shuffled deck')
  print('2. View Orginal deck')
  print('3. Quit')

  userinput = input('''Type in the number that corresponds with the feature you would like to choose ''')

  if userinput == "1":
    shuffle = shuffle(carddeck)
    print('''Shuffled your list
    ''')
    printdeck(shuffle) 
    loop = True 
  elif userinput == "2":
    printdeck(carddeck)
    loop = True
  elif userinput == "3":
    print('Thanks for playing')
    quit()
  else: 
    print('That wasnt an item from the list')
    loop = True
```

Comment: Hey! Could you point out where your error is happening?

Comment: You are returning a list from a function called `shuffle`, and naming this new list also `shuffle`. After the first call, there is no more function called `shuffle`, but a list called `shuffle`. Use a different name for the list and for the function and it'll work.

Comment: BTW, Python has a [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function for sequences. There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, is that, `shuffle` is the name of a function. In the first iteration, when you call shuffle, it assigns the value returned by `shuffle()` function which is a `list`. Now shuffle is an instance of a `list` instead of a function. So when you call shuffle again, the `shuffle` is not a function anymore and is a list and hence you get an error `list is not a callable`.

To fix this we just need to change the name of the variable that uses `shuffle` word same as that of the function. It can be anything, but make sure that they don't repeat...

In your while loop change to this:

```py
if userinput == "1":
  shuffled = shuffle(carddeck)
  print('''Shuffled your list''')
  printdeck(shuffled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there Nathan Leong,

The problem was that you used *shuffle* as a variable name and a function name. Your problem would be sorted by changing the name of the function to *Shuffle* instead.

```
from random import randint
#deckbuild function creates the deck of 52 cards from a normal deck
def deckbuild():
  #program will create a deck of cards when the program is launched
  cards = []
  signs = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
  cardletters = ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
  deck = []
  #Adding content to the deck
  for i in range(2,11):
    cards.append(str(i))
    #this will generate the numbers 2 to 10 hat will be used for the cards
  for r in range(4):
    cards.append(cardletters[r])
    #adding card letters to cards
  for final in range(4):
    for k in range(13):
      fincard = (cards[k] + " of " + signs[final])
      deck.append(fincard)
      #adds the final product of cards into a list that will be used to put into functions
  for numofcard in range(52):
    return deck

#List of functions that will be used
#shuffle function takes in a list and randomly shuffles it
def Shuffle(listinput):
  list_range = range(0, len(listinput))
  for i in list_range:
    j = randint(list_range[0], list_range[-1])
    listinput[i], listinput[j] = listinput[j], listinput[i]
  return listinput

def printdeck(x):
  print('Here is your deck of cards ')
  #prints the deck in a vertical list
  for num in range(52):
    print(x[num])


print('Hello, welcome to the card shuffler program')
print('''This program allows you to shuffle a full deck of cards in a digital world''')
loop = True
while(loop == True):
  loop = False
  carddeck = deckbuild()
  print('Here is a list of things you can do')
  print('1. Shuffle and view shuffled deck')
  print('2. View Orginal deck')
  print('3. Quit')

  userinput = input('''Type in the number that corresponds with the feature you would like to choose ''')

  if userinput == "1":
    shuffle = Shuffle(carddeck)
    print('''Shuffled your list
    ''')
    printdeck(shuffle)
    loop = True
  elif userinput == "2":
    printdeck(carddeck)
    loop = True
  elif userinput == "3":
    print('Thanks for playing')
    quit()
  else:
    print('That wasnt an item from the list')
    loop = True
```

Hope you are staying well,

bobbattalion

Comment: Better to change the name of the result to something more meaningful.

Comment: I would stick to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your variable name shuffle here:

```
if userinput == "1":
    shuffle #change this = shuffle(carddeck)
    print('''Shuffled your list
    ''')
    printdeck(shuffle) 
    loop = True
```

The reason is that python interprets it as a list variable, but then you try to call it, hence the error message you saw.